# Installing Google play services without flashing

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery-life, google-play-services, greenify

Can installing Play Services rather than flashing GApps ? I know that play services drains battery. Flashing GApps makes it as a system app and byusing greenify(as root) reduces the battery usage made by play services by force stopping it. But it restarts again.
So my question is , Is it possible to install it rather than flashing it? Cause installing it makes a non system app and greenify can do a much better work on it.

Comment: GApps includes Play Services.  What does Greenify have to do with it?  Using Greenify is orthogonal to what other apps you might have.

Comment: @MatthewRead Greenify cannot deal with system apps (unless device is rooted and/or the donation package installed – don't remember if both or just one of the two). Still, doesn't help – as Play Services must be installed as system apps or won't work correctly AFAIR.

Comment: Already saw your edit. Izzy has already answered - Play Services *has* to reside in `/system` for its privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do this, too after my first few flashes, but this did not work. As far as I know it makes a difference for some apps if they are system Apps or just installed and I think this is here the case, too. After all you could install the smallest packet, then you have got less system apps if this helps. Another idea would be to disable the background processes [as showed in this video from XDA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAqmjU_EJ8g) and then those apps should just work if you really open them up. This would not involve greenify but would have the same effect as far as I can tell.